# How to get a tuple out of a generator? Best Practice

Tags: python, syntax, tuples, generator

I'm a neophyte programmer and I wanted to create a generator that would return me two values that I would use in another function as a tuple.

I don't understand why `tuple(function_1(a,b))` returns `((1, 2),)` while `tuple(function_2(a,b))` will return a correct tuple.

I wonder what is going on here and what is the best syntax and eventually know if it is possible to retrieve a tuple from `function_1`.

Thanks in advance for any explanations!

```
>>> def function_1(a,b):
...     yield a,b
...
>>> def function_2(a,b):
...     yield a
...     yield b
...
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>>
>>> function_1(a,b)
<generator object function_1 at 0x1007931b0>
>>> function_2(a,b)
<generator object function_2 at 0x1007931f8>
>>> tuple(function_1(a,b))
((1, 2),)
>>> tuple(function_2(a,b))
(1, 2)
>>> for item in function_1(a,b):
...    print(item)
...
(1, 2)
>>> for item in function_2(a,b):
...    print(item)
...
1
2
```

Comment: What are you expecting? One tuple with values `(1, 2)`?

Comment: I don't understand. Unless I'm missing something, `Function_1` is returning tuples, while `Function_2` is returning integers.

Comment: What outcome do you expect? The first generator result in a sequence containing a single tuple `(a,b)` and the second a sequence of two elements `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your first generator yields just *once*, and yields a tuple:

```
>>> gen = function_1(1, 2)
>>> gen = function_1(1, 2)
>>> next(gen)
(1, 2)
>>> next(gen)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

The [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) takes the next value from an iterator (a generator is a specific type of iterator), if available. The `StopIteration` exception shows the generator is done and cannot produce more values.

Your second generator yields *two separate times*, each an integer:

```
>>> gen = function_2(1, 2)
>>> next(gen)
1
>>> next(gen)
2
>>> next(gen)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Calling `tuple()` on a generator will pull in *all* values the generator produces, so for `function_1` you'll get a tuple with one element, another tuple. For the second generator you'll get a tuple with two elements, the two integers. Compare that to using `list()` on the two generators:

```
>>> list(function_1(1, 2))
[(1, 2)]
>>> list(function_2(1, 2))
[1, 2]
```

Now we have two lists, but the first contains just *one* element, a tuple, because that is all that the generator produced.

As such, the two generators have fundamentally different behaviour. Pick the behaviour you need; either yield complete tuples, or yield separate values, but don't try and treat the two types of output as the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood perfectly my problem but somehow you answered it perfectly. My problem was about how to call the generator and get the tuple out of it. As you demonstrated here I should use the next() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> tuple((1,2))
(1, 2)
```

However in your case `tuple` thinks that you want to make a tuple that contains all the values in your generator.

```
>>> tuple(i for i in [(1, 2)])
((1, 2),)
```

If you want to return just two values **do no use a generator**. Generators are for returning an arbitrary number of values that are not needed all at once.

Answer (score 0):

First function yields one tuple, second function yields two separate values. In Python, every comma separated list is a tuple, the parentheses are not necessary. So to make it clear, you can write the first function as

```
def function_1(a,b):
    yield (a,b)
```

If you don't like to have a tuple, you have to yield two values, as in the second function. There is no other way.